# Export add/remove programs list to text

Tags: windows-xp

I'd like to export to a text file the list of installed software that appear in the Add/Remove program window.

Any tips on how to do that easily ?

Comment: It's even better if it doesn't involve installing another app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it this way: http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/generate-a-list-of-installed-programs-in-windows/

> Generate a List of Installed Programs in Windows
>
> To generate the list of installed programs, open the Command Prompt as
>   Administrator. To do this in Windows 7 or Windows Vista, enter “cmd”
>   (without the quotes) in the Search Programs and Files box on the Start
>   menu. The cmd.exe program should automatically be highlighted in the
>   Programs section of the results. Press Ctrl + Shift + Enter to open
>   cmd.exe as Administrator.
>
> Enter “wmic” (wmic is the Windows Management Instrumentation
>   Command-line tool) at the command line and press Enter.
>
> Enter the following line at the wmic:root\cli prompt and press Enter.
>
> /output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version
>
> NOTE: There is a space between .txt and product, between product and
>   get, and between get and name.
>
> You can also change the name of the output file and drive letter and
>   path (right after /output:) if you want to modify the output location.
>
> The InstallList.txt file is created on the root of the C: drive.

Comment: Nice tip. But the result is odd. Some apps are missing (like Chrome)...

Comment: It works, but I had to install this fix from Microsoft : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970553/

Comment: Nice job, Julien!